# Pairing AirPods Pro (2G) with Macbook without Siri

Tags: siri, airpods

I see the "connect" button on the bluetooth list and I click the button.

Then I see this window:
[image]

The question asks *if I want to enable Siri* which **I don't**!

So there is only one option for me: Cancel.

But then the AirPods is NOT connected to Macbook.

Do I really need to enable Siri to use my AirPods?